# How do you connect Azure VMs, App Services, and on-prem machines to the same vnet?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

We need a configuration set up exactly like the one described by the diagram [in this support document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#how-the-system-works). However, we already have the bottom right 2/3 configured, and it is not clear to me how the Point-to-site VPN should be configured:

[image]

Our Azure VMs and our on-premises machines share a VNet, connected via a site-to-site route-based VPN tunnel. We want to add our App Services to that VNet so they can also communicate privately with the VMs, but the [documentation for configuring a Point to Site connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) assumes you are starting from scratch, rather than adding to an existing VNet, and it does not cover Point-to-site connections to App Services.

It seems like a Point-to-site configuration needs to be added to the existing gateway, but I am unclear on several issues not covered by the documentation: How are certificates handled? What tunnel type is supported/preferred in App Services. Should the address pool of the Point-to-site config match the VNet's Gateway subnet range?

**Update:** After adding an address pool value for the Point-to-side configuration in the existing VNet gateway, the VNet could be added to our App Service. But even though The App Service VNet config reports that certs are in sync and that the gateway status is online, the App Service does not seem to be able to communicate with a VM, and nothing is listed under Allocated IP addresses in the Point-to-side configuration.

I am not sure if additional configuration is needed or if this implies a problem with the VNet addressing. The VNet default subnet is `10.1.0.0/24`, the VNet gateway subnet is `10.1.1.0/24`, and the Point-to-site pool is `10.1.2.0/24`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are certificates handled?

You don't need to create certificates for the Point-to-Site configuration. Certificates are automatically created when you connect your WebApp to the VNet using the portal.

> What tunnel type is supported/preferred in App Services?

This is a reference to the P2S VPN features, you can take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json#planningtable). P2S supports the protocols such as Secure Sockets Tunneling Protocol (SSTP) and IPsec.

> Should the address pool of the Point-to-site config match the VNet's
>   Gateway subnet range?

You should not match the address pool of P2S with VNet's Gateway subnet. They are two address pools with different network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to connect the WebApp to the VNet after giving the Point-to-site config an address pool range. However, I still can't communicate between the WebApp and the VMs. I updated the question with more info.

Comment: With my understanding of the document, the address space of the P2S should not be a subnet address space of the VNet. For you, just like that, the address space would not be any range in 10.1.0.0 - 10.1.255.255. You can set the space in 172.16.0.0/16 like the example in the document.

Comment: I made the change, but unfortunately it's still unable to communicate. I think we're much closer now, so I'll accept this answer and create a new question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: We determined the problem: `If your gateway already exists with point-to-site enabled, and it is not in the basic SKU, IKEV2 must be disabled in your point-to-site configuration.` Ours was non-basic, and after disabling IKEv2 *and* deleting and re-adding the vnet to the App Service, the connection worked. But none of the IP information populated in the point-to-site status page until after we attempted to connect, suggesting the IP assignments happen on-demand. Very confusing considering there is no other indication of a problem in Azure.

Comment: Maybe it describe a little of it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-gateway-settings#feature). And the Basic SKU has certain feature limitations.